# How to use IntervalIndex to generate .cat.codes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories, categorical-data

I have a dataset that I'll `qcut` and form categories as a `pandas.core.indexes.interval.IntervalIndex`.

How can I categorize future datasets using those same categories that I've generated from the original dataset?

**Explanatory Code:**

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed(42)

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

>>> df
    A   B   C   D
 0  51  92  14  71
 1  60  20  82  86
 2  74  74  87  99
 3  23  2   21  52
 4  1   87  29  37
 5  1   63  59  20
 6  32  75  57  21
 7  88  48  90  58
 8  41  91  59  79
 9  14  61  61  46

>>> categories_a = pd.qcut(df['A'], 4).cat.categories

>>> type(categories_a)
pandas.core.indexes.interval.IntervalIndex

>>> categories_a
IntervalIndex([(0.999, 16.25], (16.25, 36.5], (36.5, 57.75], (57.75, 88.0]]
          closed='right',
          dtype='interval[float64]')
```

**What I have tried:**

I have tried to use `CategoricalDtype` and things like `df['B'].astype(categories_a)` without success. I am running out of ideas on how to this in an elegant fashion.

**Expected Results:**

Given that `df` and  `categories_a` are the same as above, I would like to convert all elements in `df['B']` according to `.cat.codes` as the ones that would be generated by `pd.qcut(df['A'], 4).cat.codes`. Output would look like:

```
df['B'] 
original --> processed # comment
92 --> 3 # (57.75, 88.0] this one actually goes through the roof
20 --> 1 # (16.25, 36.5]
74 --> 3 # (57.75, 88.0]
2  --> 0 # (0.999, 16.25]
87 --> 3 # (57.75, 88.0]
63 --> 3 # (57.75, 88.0]
75 --> 3 # (57.75, 88.0]
48 --> 2 # (36.5, 57.75]
91 --> 3 # (57.75, 88.0]
61 --> 3 # (57.75, 88.0]
```

I hope that is clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same logic as above, but to get the categories rather than the ranges in your processed dataframe:

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))


series, bins = pd.qcut(df["A"], 4, retbins=True, labels=False)
def apply_cut(df):
    for i in df.columns:
        df[i] = pd.cut(df[i], bins=bins, labels=False, include_lowest=True)
    return df

processed = apply_cut(df)
```

Returns:

```
>>> processed
   A    B    C    D
0  2  NaN  0.0  3.0
1  3  1.0  3.0  3.0
2  3  3.0  3.0  NaN
3  1  0.0  1.0  2.0
4  0  3.0  1.0  2.0
5  0  3.0  3.0  1.0
6  1  3.0  2.0  1.0
7  3  2.0  NaN  3.0
8  2  NaN  3.0  3.0
9  0  3.0  3.0  2.0
```

If you wanted to get rid of the NaNs and put them force them into their closest categories, you can do the same, but adding `-float(np.inf)` and `float(np.inf)` to the first and last bin:

```
series, bins = pd.qcut(df["A"], 4, retbins=True, labels=False)
bins[0] = -float(np.inf)
bins[-1] = float(np.inf)
def apply_cut(df):
    for i in df.columns:
        df[i] = pd.cut(df[i], bins=bins, labels=False, include_lowest=True,right=False)
    return df

processed = apply_cut(df)

>>> processed
   A  B  C  D
0  2  3  0  3
1  3  1  3  3
2  3  3  3  3
3  1  0  1  2
4  0  3  1  2
5  0  3  3  1
6  1  3  2  1
7  3  2  3  3
8  2  3  3  3
9  0  3  3  2
```

---

#### piR edit

Please delete/alter as you see fit.  This is your post and I'm intruding (-:

```
bins = pd.qcut(df.A, 4, retbins=True)[1]
bins[0] -= np.finfo(np.float).resolution

df.apply(lambda c: pd.cut(c, bins))

               A              B              C              D
0  (36.5, 57.75]            NaN   (1.0, 16.25]  (57.75, 88.0]
1  (57.75, 88.0]  (16.25, 36.5]  (57.75, 88.0]  (57.75, 88.0]
2  (57.75, 88.0]  (57.75, 88.0]  (57.75, 88.0]            NaN
3  (16.25, 36.5]   (1.0, 16.25]  (16.25, 36.5]  (36.5, 57.75]
4   (1.0, 16.25]  (57.75, 88.0]  (16.25, 36.5]  (36.5, 57.75]
5   (1.0, 16.25]  (57.75, 88.0]  (57.75, 88.0]  (16.25, 36.5]
6  (16.25, 36.5]  (57.75, 88.0]  (36.5, 57.75]  (16.25, 36.5]
7  (57.75, 88.0]  (36.5, 57.75]            NaN  (57.75, 88.0]
8  (36.5, 57.75]            NaN  (57.75, 88.0]  (57.75, 88.0]
9   (1.0, 16.25]  (57.75, 88.0]  (57.75, 88.0]  (36.5, 57.75]
```

Or:

```
bins = pd.qcut(df.A, 4, retbins=True)[1]
bins[0] = -float(np.inf)
bins[-1] = float(np.inf)

processed = df.apply(lambda c: pd.cut(c, bins, labels=False))

>>> processed
   A  B  C  D
0  2  3  0  3
1  3  1  3  3
2  3  3  3  3
3  1  0  1  2
4  0  3  1  2
5  0  3  3  1
6  1  3  2  1
7  3  2  3  3
8  2  3  3  3
9  0  3  3  2
```

Comment: I forgot about `retbins`  This element of the answer is better than mine.  Though I do like my implementation better.  IMO, accept this answer but I'll leave mine for reference.

Comment: Absolutely.  Please feel free to combine them in your answer.

Comment: No worries, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can stitch together the left and right end points of the intervals in order to build `bins` for use in `pd.cut`.

```
def cut_by_cats(cats):
    bins = [c[0].left] + [i.right for i in c]
    def cut_(series):
        return pd.cut(series, bins)
    return cut_

cut = cut_by_cats(pd.qcut(df.A, 4).cat.categories)

df.apply(cut)

                A               B               C              D
0   (36.5, 57.75]             NaN  (0.999, 16.25]  (57.75, 88.0]
1   (57.75, 88.0]   (16.25, 36.5]   (57.75, 88.0]  (57.75, 88.0]
2   (57.75, 88.0]   (57.75, 88.0]   (57.75, 88.0]            NaN
3   (16.25, 36.5]  (0.999, 16.25]   (16.25, 36.5]  (36.5, 57.75]
4  (0.999, 16.25]   (57.75, 88.0]   (16.25, 36.5]  (36.5, 57.75]
5  (0.999, 16.25]   (57.75, 88.0]   (57.75, 88.0]  (16.25, 36.5]
6   (16.25, 36.5]   (57.75, 88.0]   (36.5, 57.75]  (16.25, 36.5]
7   (57.75, 88.0]   (36.5, 57.75]             NaN  (57.75, 88.0]
8   (36.5, 57.75]             NaN   (57.75, 88.0]  (57.75, 88.0]
9  (0.999, 16.25]   (57.75, 88.0]   (57.75, 88.0]  (36.5, 57.75]
```